# Problem with enclosing csv.Reader in using block and deleting file after uploading

Tags: csvhelper

I need to delete my csv file after importing its contents into my database. When I try to do that I get a system.io exception saying the file is being used by another process.  I have tried enclosing the read in a using block but the files are not then read to my target IEnumerable.  My code is below - any assistance in figuring this out greatly appreciated.

When I call csv.Read to generate learningTasksList within a using block, learningTasksList is null.  But if I omit the using block - as in the uncommented-out code below, leanringTasksList is populated correctly.  However, I get the list of objects but the process is not disposed of and I cannot delete the file uploaded file afterwards

```
private IEnumerable<LearningTask> GenerateNewLearningTasksList(string filePathToImport)
    {


        //using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePathToImport))
        //using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
        //{
        //    csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;  
        //    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;  

        //    try
        //    {
        //        var learningTasksList = csv.GetRecords<LearningTask>();
        //        return learningTasksList;
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        Log.Error("Error generating list of new Learning Tasks from csv  - {Error}", ex.InnerException);
        //        return null;
        //    }
        //}


        //This works but I am unable to dispose of it after I have transferred the records to learningTasksList
        var reader = new StreamReader(filePathToImport);
        var csv = new CsvReader(reader);
        csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;  
        csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null; 

        try
        {
            var learningTasksList = csv.GetRecords<LearningTask>();
            return learningTasksList;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error generating list of new Learning Tasks from csv  - {Error}", ex.InnerException);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CsvHelper [Getting Started](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started) page.

> The `GetRecords<T>` method will return an `IEnumerable<T>` that will `yield` records. What this means is that only a single record is returned at a time as you iterate the records. That also means that only a small portion of the file is read into memory. Be careful though. If you do anything that executes a LINQ projection, such as calling `.ToList()`, the entire file will be read into memory.

One way to solve this would be to call `ToList()` from within the using block of the `StreamReader` and `CsvReader`.

```cs
var learningTasksList = csv.GetRecords<LearningTask>().ToList();
```

If you don't want to read the whole file into memory at once, you will have to pass in the `CsvReader` to your `GenerateNewLearningTasksList()` method and then close the connection to the `StreamReader` after you have finished enumerating `learningTasksList`.